# unable to install egit on eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have Eclipse Indigo ( I know its an old version, but for some of the reasons, I need to use it for my job, since other plugins and projects are qualified with it).
I am trying to install Egit plugin,(v 3.7 so that it matches with Indigo) so I can start working with projects on git too.
But, each time I try to do that it throws errors like:-

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.7.1.201504261725-r (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.7.1.201504261725-r)
  Missing requirement: Apache HttpComponents HttpClient OSGi bundle 4.1.3.v201209201135 (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.1.3.v201209201135) requires 'package org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.4.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.7.1.201504261725-r (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.7.1.201504261725-r)
    To: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [4.1.3.v201209201135]
```

Can anyone suggest me what do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have, is that the package you have downloaded, is missing a component that it cannot operate without,

I would suggest either redowload/install the files or find another source of the raw file to download.

-I hope this helps

Comment: I downloaded the archive from the p2 repo download location
http://eclipse.mirror.rafal.ca/egit/updates-3.7.1/
It still kept giving me errors , and then I removed the components which were giving errors, but still failed to install.
And this is the error trace

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Its not allowing me to put the whole trace here, also seems like support has been removed for older versions of eclipse.